# Erlang Tip&Tricks reducing memory footprint for gen_server ssl socket

Tags: sockets, memory, ssl, erlang, gen-server

Does anyone would have an idea on how to reduce memory footprint for an Erlang gen_server ssl socket oriented ?

Right now each client (gen_server) has a something like 128 Ko in memory. while in C++ I have more something like 40 Ko per client.

Like:

- Changing the ssl cipher, would it change the memory footprint ?
- Changing the buffer size ?

I'm really looking for any idea that would drastically reduce memory footprint !

EDIT 1 : 
I'm already using hibernate_after option.

Answer (score 2):

If your application does not need support for TLS session reuse, you could set the `session_cb` environment parameter of the `ssl` application to your own  "NULL implementation".

Comment: That seems to be a great idea, not sure how to done it though on top of my head... But I'll look into it, let you know if I get any good results...

Comment: [null_ssl_session_cb.erl](http://pastebin.com/xna4qJYe) and `{ssl, [{session_cb, null_ssl_session_cb}]}` in your `sys.config`

Comment: looks like difference of using it or not using it are too small :(